# Get preview image for remote video

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avkit

I have a link to the video (for example: http://example.com/video.mp4). I need to get the first frame of the video.
I use:

```
func getPreviewImage(_ url: URL) -> UIImage? {
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
    let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    do {
        let cgImage = try generator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: nil)
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return nil
}
```

However, this does not work.
I get the following error in the logs:

> Code=-1102 "You do not have permission to access the requested
>   resource.

Tell me how to get the first frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
func getThumbnailImageFromVideoURL(fromUrl url: URL) -> UIImage? {
    let asset: AVAsset = AVAsset(url: url)
    let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)

    do {
        let thumbnailImage = try imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 60) , actualTime: nil)
        return UIImage(cgImage: thumbnailImage)
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: same problem (You do not have permission to access the requested resource.)

Comment: @КузинДмитрий, This code works fine. please share video URL so i can test.

Comment: @КузинДмитрий, Problem is with that link. I suggest you to please try with different video link.